# Counting empty and non-empty files within directories in Bash

Tags: bash

Unfortunately I do not have any code as a starting point as I have no idea where to begin. I need to create a bash script named dircheck that allows the user to run the program with a directory path (`e.g. ./dircheck ~Documents/unit/backup`) and for the script to output to the terminal the following:

> *name of directory entered* has:
> x empty files,
> x files with data,
> x empty directories,
> x non-empty directories

As you can see I need to output how many files the directory has that are empty, how many files the directory has that have data, how many directories that are empty, and how many directories that have data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look for these topics: Processing command-line arguments (*positional parameters*); Looping over files (`for f in *`, *for loops* and *wildcards*); Variables and arithmetics; Testing for files and directories (the `test` built-in command). You'll know what to do next.

Comment: You should look up the [*find(1)* command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html). You should be able to combine the `-type`, `-empty` and `-maxdepth` flags to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in comments, GNU find can do this fairly easily.

```
#!/bin/bash -
echo "$1 has:"
find "$1" -mindepth 1 -type f,d \
  \( -empty -o -printf 'non-' \) -printf 'empty ' \
  \( -type f -printf 'files' -o -printf 'directories' \) \
  -printf '\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

You can restrict the analysis to the first level entries only by adding `-maxdepth 1` to the *find* invocation. Anyway, its output will look like this:

```
$ ./foo ./bionic
./bionic has:
      7 empty files
    175 non-empty directories
   2163 non-empty files
```

Comment: Hi @oguz ismail thanks for your help! Is there a way to do this without using the find command?

Comment: Dunno, there may be

Answer (score 1):

I would propose this as another way with `dircheck.sh`, by a bash function to check recursively a given directory, using only bash intrinsic syntax (shell glob) - without calling outer command:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# check recursively a directory:
#
function checkDirr() {
  for x in $1/*
  do

    #
    # if it's a sub-directory:
    #
    if [ -d $x ]; then
      #echo "$x is a directory."
      ndirs=$((ndirs + 1))
      #
      # glob all entries in an array:
      #
      entries_array=($x/*)
      #
      # check entries array count:
      #
      if [ ${#entries_array[*]} -eq 0 ]; then
        #echo "empty dir"
        nemptydirs=$((nemptydirs + 1))
      else
        #
        # call recursively myself to check non-empty sub-directory:
        #
        checkDirr $x

      fi

    #
    # otherwise it's a file:
    #
    else
      #echo "$x is a file."
      nfiles=$((nfiles + 1))
      #
      # check empty file:
      #
      if [ ! -s $x ]; then
        nemptyfiles=$((nemptyfiles + 1))
      fi
    fi

  done
}

#
# main():
#
#
# initialize globals:
#
ndirs=0
nfiles=0

nemptydirs=0
nemptyfiles=0

#
# use given directory path or the current directory .:
#
dir0=${1:-.}

#
# set shell nullglob option to avoid dir/* string when dir is empty:
#
shopt -s nullglob

#
# now check recursively the directory:
#
checkDirr $dir0

#
# unset shell nullglob option:
#
shopt -u nullglob

#
# send statistics:
#
echo $dir0 has:
echo
echo $nemptyfiles empty files
echo $((nfiles - nemptyfiles)) files with data
echo $nemptydirs empty directories
echo $((ndirs - nemptydirs)) non-empty directories
```

This gives for example

```
$ dircheck.sh so
```

> so has:
>
> 2 empty files

> 87 files with data

> 3 empty directories

> 11 non-empty directories